# Why can HTTP/HTTPS proxy and Socks proxy work on one single port?

Tags: http, tcp, proxy, network-programming

Many proxy soft provides multiple protocol over one port.

1.
Is there any byte (above or in TCP/UDP package) reserved to mark which protocol client is using?

As I know, HTTP protocol is just carried by TCP's data segment, and there is no any other mark.

So how proxy software tell the protocol when received a request?
(By guessing the first one or two bytes received? It doesn't sounds a good idea)

2.
What's the difference between HTTP proxy and HTTPS proxy?

Here are my guesses

"HTTP proxy" only means a service that can provide proxy for HTTP protocol, And a "HTTPS proxy" can provides service for HTTPS protocol? (means the only difference is whether they can deal HTTP CONNECT method) So the HTTPS proxy is just a functionally enhanced HTTP proxy

Or

HTTPS proxy offers extra security layer between client and proxy server? (to protect the HTTP CONNECT method headers?) So the communication process is quite different between HTTP proxy and HTTPS
proxy, and both HTTP proxy and HTTPS proxy can service HTTP/HTTPS protocol ?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is there any byte (above or in TCP/UDP package) reserved to mark which protocol client is using?

It is not a single byte, but a HTTP request is clearly distinguishable from a SOCKS request, as a look at the respective standards (RFC 7230, RFC 1928) would show. It isn't the case that all protocols can be easily distinguished, but it is true for SOCKS and HTTP.

> 2. What's the difference between HTTP proxy and HTTPS proxy?

A HTTPS proxy is a HTTP proxy used for `https://` requests. This is done by using the [CONNECT method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT) to create a tunnel through the proxy to the final server and then doing end-to-end HTTPS (TLS+HTTP) inside this tunnel.

> ... Or HTTPS proxy offers extra security layer between client and proxy server?

This exists too, but it is usually called "HTTP proxy over TLS", "HTTP proxy over HTTPS", "encrypted proxy connection" or similar, but not "HTTPS proxy".

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the first question with practicality:

> 1. Is there any byte (above or in TCP/UDP package) reserved to mark which protocol client is using?

Both HTTP and SOCKS proxies run over TCP and not UDP. TCP abstracts a *stream* to the application layer and does not provide an interface of "packets".

While there's no explicit mark on which protocol the TCP stream carries, *valid* HTTP and SOCKS proxy requests are easily distinguishable:

- An HTTP proxy request, just like normal HTTP request, begins with an HTTP verb (e.g. `GET` or `CONNECT`).
- A SOCKS request begins with the version number (4 or 5) in binary.

Assuming that we only need to handle HTTP and SOCKS, this provides a simple yet 100% effective heuristic: If the first byte in the TCP stream is `0x04` or `0x05`, then it's a SOCKS client; otherwise it's an HTTP client.

A wide range of existing software that supports the so-called "mixed-port" feature identifies SOCKS from HTTP in this way: Examples include [3proxy](https://github.com/3proxy/3proxy/commit/fb56b7d307a7bce1f2109c73864bad7c71716f3b#diff-e268b23274bc9df1b2c0957dfa85d684519282ed611f6135e795205e53fb6e3b) and [glider](https://github.com/nadoo/glider/blob/master/proxy/mixed/mixed.go).